# Controllers in subfolders ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.Net MVC 4 project, I have a controllers in a sub-folder in controller folder-

```
/Controllers
    /GroupA
        /AbcController.cs
```

In AbcController, i have two methods-

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(string value)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = value;
        return View();
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs -

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "TestRoute",
            url: "GroupA/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AbcController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }               
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

but when i browse `http://localhost:2240/groupa/abc/edit/somevalue`

, 'somevalue' is not passed to the method. It shows null.

What i am missing here?

Comment: if I recall correctly, isn't it solved by either `.../groupa/abc/edit?somevalue` as url or changing `public ActionResult Edit(string value)` to `public ActionResult Edit(string id)` i.e. you name your parameter `id` in the route, but `value` in the method

Comment: [MVC Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) will give you another hierarchical level for your routes ("subfolders").

Comment: @Jasen, Yes MVC `Area` is the way to go. Before I also used the way OP is doing, but only recently I learnt about `Areas` and it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your route, your parameter is declared as `id` while in your action method it's declared as `value`. Pick one and stick to it.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TestRoute",
    url: "GroupA/{controller}/{action}/{value}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AbcController", action = "Index", value = UrlParameter.Optional }               
);

public ActionResult Edit(string value)
{
    ViewBag.Message = value;
    return View();
}
```

Edit : while we're on the subject, I recommend you give [AttributeRouting](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting) a look.